# How to download a file (both http and https) and see/show download progress in real time in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

First of all, I am a noob. I want to create an online downloader as part of my self-learning. I want to download files from both HTTP and HTTPS using nodejs. And I also want to show/see the progress of downloading. I there any way to do that.

My Code

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
const request = http.get("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `axios` module and you can pass `URL` and it will take care of a protocol `http` or `https`. See below code

```
'use strict'
const Fs = require('fs')  
const Path = require('path')  
const Axios = require('axios')  
const ProgressBar = require('progress')

async function downloadImage () {  
  const url = 'http://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4'

  console.log('Connecting …')
  const { data, headers } = await Axios({
    url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'stream'
  })
  const totalLength = headers['content-length']

  console.log('Starting download')
  const progressBar = new ProgressBar('-> downloading [:bar] :percent :etas', {
      width: 40,
      complete: '=',
      incomplete: ' ',
      renderThrottle: 1,
      total: parseInt(totalLength)
    })

  const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(
    Path.resolve(__dirname, '', 'test.mp4')
  )

  data.on('data', (chunk) => {
    progressBar.tick(chunk.length)
   console.log("% complted",(progressBar.curr/totalLength)*100)
  })
  data.pipe(writer)
}

downloadImage()
```

Source: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/axios-download-progress-in-node-js

Demo here: https://repl.it/repls/FluffyAmpleArrays

Comment: This will do, but be aware that setting a `data` listener on your input stream may [prevent backpressure from being applied by the destination writable stream (the input stream becomes greedy)](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/stream.html#stream_event_data). If you download a large file and your filesystem is slower than your network, Node.js could run out of memory.